# How to get the input values from a jQuery popup window

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i had created a jquery popup window for login box.it contains the fields of email & password.i want to get the input values entered in jquery popup for checking the username & password with mysql db. iam not able to get the values from popup.

can any one suggest me to get out from this??

My HTML code:

```
<div class="login-box"><a href="#login-box" class="login-window">Login</a></div>

<div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
  <a href="#" class="close"><img src="close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>
  <form method="post" class="signin" id="sign" action="" >
    <fieldset class="textbox">
      <label class="username">
        <!-- <span>Username or email</span>-->
        <input id="username" name="username" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Email">
      </label>

      <label class="password">
        <!--   <span>Password</span>-->
        <input id="password" name="password" value="" type="password" placeholder="Password">
      </label>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <button class="submit button" type="button" name="submit" >Login</button>

      <p class="forgot"><a  href="#">Forgot your password?</a></p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

My jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.login-window').click(function() {

        // Getting the variable's value from a link 
        var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');

        //Fade in the Popup and add close button
        $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);

        //Set the center alignment padding + border
        var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2; 
        var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2; 

        $(loginBox).css({ 
            'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
            'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
        });

        // Add the mask to body
        $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
        $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

        return false;
    });

    // When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
    $('a.close, #mask').live('click', function() { 
        $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
            $('#mask').remove();  
        }); 
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Why aren't you able to get the values? Use `$("#username").val()` and `$("#password").val()`?

Comment: BTW, `.live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in 1.9. Use `.on()` now.

Comment: Do you wanna get values in your parent window? If so WHY?

Comment: i had used those $("#username").val() and $("#password").val() in the jquery iam not getting the values to the ajax function $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "process.php", data: {user: uname,pwd: pass}, success: function(a){ $('#login-box').html(a); } });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you were not able to get the values of the fields from the pop up. Turns out , it can be obtained.

I have modified your code a bit for that purpose and just did a plain retrieve on click of the login button .

Also, your posted mark up has some tags which have not been ended.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="login-box"><a href="#login-box" class="login-window">Login</a></div>

<div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
  <a href="#" class="close"><img src="close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>
  <form method="post" class="signin" id="sign" action="" >
    <fieldset class="textbox">
      <label class="username">
        <!-- <span>Username or email</span>-->
          <input id="username" name="username" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Email"/>
      </label>

      <label class="password">
        <!--   <span>Password</span>-->
          <input id="password" name="password" value="" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
      </label>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <button class="submit button" id="subMitBtn" type="button" name="submit" >Login</button>

      <p class="forgot"><a  href="#">Forgot your password?</a></p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#subMitBtn").click(function() {

        var userName =  $("#username").val();
        var password =  $("#password").val();
        console.log("userName::"+userName);
        console.log("password::"+password);
    });

});
```

As i said, i am not very sure what your full functionality of js does, so i have trimmed it fairly in the code above , just to show the retrieval of the fields.

Here's a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/cVm7W/

Run it and see in your browser console, you will find the values or give alerts in case of IE.

Answer (score 1):

Try tou use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) for checking in `mysql db`

and for getting values of `username` and `password` try this,

```
$('a.login-window').click(function() {

    // Getting the variable's value from a link 
    var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');
    //Fade in the Popup and add close button
    $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);
    //Set the center alignment padding + border
    var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2; 
    var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2; 

    var uname=$("#username").val();
    var pass=$("#password").val();
    // use the above values in Ajax function


    $(loginBox).css({ 
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });
    // Add the mask to body
    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
    $('#mask').fadeIn(300);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "process.php",
 data: {user: uname,pwd: pass},
 success: function(a){
 $('#login-box').html(a);
 }
});
i am using this ajax code to check with db am i doing right??